# How can I get an extension method to change the original object in Dart?

Tags: flutter, class, object, dart, extension-methods

I have `bounds`. bounds should be extended with new LatLng.

```
var bounds = LatLngBounds();
for (var latlng in _list) bounds.extend(latlng);
```

I want to implement this extension:

```
extension LatLngBoundsExtend on LatLngBounds {
  extend(LatLng _latLng){
    //I want to change the object which this method is called from
    this = LatLngBounds(southwest: /* some magic code*/, northeast: /* some magic code*/   );

  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot change the original object with extension. Your best options would be to return a new object with the edited data but you lose the interest of using an extension.

Comment: Dart extension should have some improvement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been possible to change the original object if its properties were not final. [This is not the case for `LatLngBounds.southwest` and `LatLngBounds.northeast`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/d44d155fa501c6bd5ea5c6d79e13cdeaa4274c70/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/lib/src/types/location.dart#L76-L80).

Comment: I meant to change the object. But not properties.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, `LatLngBounds` is an immutable class representing a latitude/longitude aligned rectangle.

```dart
final myLatLngBounds = LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
myLatLngBounds.extend(latlng);
```

If this `extend` modifies `this` how would you access this?

I think this `extend` should rather be part of some kind of State Management.

See the following, using [Riverpod Hooks package](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod):

Instead of changing the object (since it is immutable), you return a new one in your extension:

```dart
extension RectX on Rect {
  Rect extend(Offset offset) {
    return Rect.fromLTRB(
      min(left, offset.dx),
      min(top, offset.dy),
      max(right, offset.dx),
      max(bottom, offset.dy),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, when you need to modify the object, you work on a State Object managed by Flutter or any other [State Management System](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options):

```dart
final rectProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<RectNotifier>((ref) => RectNotifier());

class RectNotifier extends StateNotifier<Rect> {
  RectNotifier([Rect state])
      : super(state ?? Rect.fromLTRB(100, 100, 200, 200));

  void extend(Offset offset) {
    state = state.extend(offset);
  }
}
```

### Here is a Minimal Working Example:

[image]

```dart
import 'dart:math' show min, max;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final rect = useProvider(rectProvider.state);
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (details) =>
            context.read(rectProvider).extend(details.localPosition),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black12,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: rect.top,
                left: rect.left,
                child: Container(
                    width: rect.width,
                    height: rect.height,
                    color: Colors.amber.shade400),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final rectProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<RectNotifier>((ref) => RectNotifier());

class RectNotifier extends StateNotifier<Rect> {
  RectNotifier([Rect state])
      : super(state ?? Rect.fromLTRB(100, 100, 200, 200));

  void extend(Offset offset) {
    state = state.extend(offset);
  }
}

extension RectX on Rect {
  Rect extend(Offset offset) {
    return Rect.fromLTRB(
      min(left, offset.dx),
      min(top, offset.dy),
      max(right, offset.dx),
      max(bottom, offset.dy),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the fields if they are not final. But you cannot change object as `this = new Class()`.

PS.
`southwest` and `northeast` are `final` fields of `LatLngBounds`. So you can't change them with an extension
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/lib/src/types/location.dart

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods can *mutate* `this`, but they cannot reassign/rebind it.  Note that that is true for normal methods too and isn't specific to extension methods.

Suppose that reassigning `this` were possible.  Consider the following code:

```dart
var foo = Foo();
var sameFoo = foo;

foo.reassignThis();
```

Would `foo` and `sameFoo` still refer to the same object?  It would be surprising if they now referred to different objects.  However, if they do still refer to the same object, that would mean that the VM/runtime would need to be able to easily and quickly find *all* references to an object so that it can update them.

Even if the VM/runtime could do that, then consider:

```dart
class Base {
  Base(this.x);

  int x;

  void reassignThis() {
    this = Base(x + 1); // Not legal!
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  Derived(int x) : super(x);

  int y;
}

void main() {
  var derived = Derived(0);
  derived.reassignThis();
  print(derived.y);
}
```

After calling `reassignThis()`, what would `derived` be?  Would it still be a `Derived` object?  Would it be just a `Base` object?

Reassigning `this` isn't possible, and it isn't something that could be improved; fundamentally it doesn't make much sense.

---

Now, instead of reassigning `this`, you could implement something like:

```dart
class MyLatLngBounds implements LatLngBounds {
  MyLatLngBounds(this._actual);

  LatLngBounds _actual;

  LatLng get northeast => _actual.northeast;
  LatLng get southwest => _actual.southwest;
  // ... other methods that forward to [_actual] ...

  void extend(LatLng _latLng) {
    _actual = LatLngBounds(/* some magic code */);
  }
}
```

and then try to use `MyLatLngBounds` everywhere instead of `LatLngBounds`.